# How to print double pointer array

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, vector, printf

I have two double pointer array, which I want to print

but somehow I am not able to do it..

```
double *noise_feature = new double[5];
double *basic_feature = new double[39];
noise_feature_extraction(sig, len, noise_feature);
basic_feature_extraction(sig, len, basic_feature);

cout << "\n";
printf("Noice features are");
for (auto i = noise_feature.begin(); i != noise_feature.end(); ++i) 
    cout << *i << " "; 
cout << "\n";

printf("Basic features are");
for (auto i = basic_feature.begin(); i != basic_feature.end(); ++i) 
    cout << *i << " "; 
cout << "\n";
```

This gives error like this

```
Pan_Tompkins.cpp:992:29: error: member reference base type 'double *' is not a structure or union
        for (auto i = noise_feature.begin(); i != noise_feature.end(); ++i) 
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
Pan_Tompkins.cpp:992:57: error: member reference base type 'double *' is not a structure or union
        for (auto i = noise_feature.begin(); i != noise_feature.end(); ++i)
```

I tried printing this way

```
printf("%g",noise_feature);
printf("%g",basic_feature);
```

This does not give error but also does not print anything.

How can I print this two double array to see their value?

Comment: You should use a `std::vector<double>` instead of allocating a double array.

Answer (score 2):

You request a raw array on the heap and discard the info how many elements it has. Recall that

```
double *noise_feature = new double[5];
```

declares nothing but a pointer to `double`. The fact that you know it's a contiguous array of length 5 can be used in different way. Either you keep that magic number literal in your code;

```
for (auto value = noise_feature; value != noise_feature + 5; ++value) 
    //       not maintainable, but works: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    cout << *value << " ";
```

Or you go with a raw array on the stack. Here, the length is baked into the type and hence not lost. You could use a range-based for loop to iterate over it, for example.

```
double noise_features[5];

// ...

for (double value : noise_features)
    std::cout << value << ' ';
```

However, the preferred solution is using either `std::vector` if the size of your sequence is only known at runtime, or `std::array` if it's a fixed-length sequence.

Comment: perhaps also worth mentioning that with the array one can use `std::begin(noise_feature)` and `std::end(noise_features)` (which is basically what the range based loop does under the hood)

Comment: Not basically, but exactly!

Answer (score 2):

You declared two pointers

```
double *noise_feature = new double[5];
double *basic_feature = new double[39];
```

Pointers are scalar objects that do not have the member functions `begin` and `end`.

So you have to use the magic numbers `5` and `39` to output the allocated arrays pointed to by the pointers.

For example

```
cout << "\n";
printf("Noice features are");
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) 
    cout << noise_feature[i] << " "; 
cout << "\n";

printf("Basic features are");
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 39; ++i ) 
    cout << basic_feature[i] << " "; 
cout << "\n";
```

The same can be done using pointers as for example

```
cout << "\n";
printf("Noice features are");
for ( auto p = noise_feature; p != noise_feature + 5; ++p ) 
    cout << *p << " "; 
cout << "\n";

printf("Basic features are");
for ( auto p = basic_feature; p != basic_feature + 39; ++p ) 
    cout << *p << " "; 
cout << "\n";
```

Pay attention to that instead of "manually" allocating dynamically arrays you could use the standard container `std::vector` as for example

```
#include <vector>

//...

std::vector<double> noise_feature( 5 );

//...

cout << "\n";
printf("Noice features are");
for ( const auto &item : noise_feature ) 
    cout << item << " "; 
cout << "\n";

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays defined with statements like `array_name[element_count]` are not objects of any class!**

Arrays are actually pointers to continuous memory. So, they don't have any methods and member functions. So your code will fail to compile. So instead of this:

```cpp
for (auto i = noise_feature.begin(); i != noise_feature.end(); ++i)
```

Use this:

```cpp
for (auto i = noise_feature; i != noise_feature + 5; ++i)
```

Or this:

```cpp
for (auto i = std::begin(noise_feature); i != std::end(noise_feature); ++i)
```

Or you can store it in a `std::vector<double>` object. Also, why you used `printf` when C++ provides `std::cout` ?

Comment: "Arrays defined with statements like array_name[element_count] are not objects! Arrays are actually pointers to continuous memory" These statements are entirely wrong.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why? Yes, they are objects but not objects of a class.